# Spring 4.2.0 - How to use SimpUserRegistry

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-websocket

According with the Spring 4.2.0 documentation, item 5.5, I'm trying to use SimpUserRegistry to get the users list connected to an websockets/STOMP endpoint ...but I'm pretty new on Spring and I just don't know where/how to use this class. Can you provide me an example or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just inject `SimpUserRegistry` as a dependency. Here's an example on printing the username of all  connected users:

```
@Autowired private SimpUserRegistry userRegistry;

public void printConnectedUsers() { 
    userRegistry.getUsers().stream()
                    .map(u -> u.getName())
                    .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer this simple question

Answer (score 3):

Just been battling a similar issue - thought I'd leave the findings here for future travellers.

I was trying to use a `WebSocketSecurityInterceptor` that contained the above Autowired `SimpUserRegistry` in order to make decisions about which messages should be sent. This involved setting the interceptor in the `WebSocketConfig`; because I needed the Autowired field, I couldn't just use the interceptor's constructor like normal.

```
@Component
public class WebSocketSecurityInterceptor implements ChannelInterceptor {

    @Autowired
    private SimpUserRegistry simpUserRegistry;

    ...other stuff
}
```

and

```
 @Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Autowired 
    private WebSocketSecurityInterceptor webSocketSecurityInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/stream");
        config.configureBrokerChannel().setInterceptors(webSocketSecurityInterceptor);
    }
```

Unfortunately in the above, due to some quirk of initialisation order, when you Autowire classes into `WebSocketConfig`, the `configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config)` is no longer run, and so the interceptor is not added.

The only way round we could find is rummaging around horribly in the application context to get the right bean instead:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Autowired private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/stream");
        config.configureBrokerChannel().setInterceptors(config.configureBrokerChannel().setInterceptors(applicationContext.getBean(WebSocketSecurityInterceptor.class));
    }
```