# Sending messages to specific user with Spring Websocket

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-websocket, stomp

I set up a WebSocket with spring decribed in this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/. What i need is that my Server send out a message to specific users every 5 seconds. So i first made this:

```java
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
public void greet() {
    template.convertAndSend("/topic/greetings", new Greeting("Bufff!"));
}
```

And it works. Now to send messages only to specific users i changed the following:

```java
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
public void greet() {
   template.convertAndSendToUser("MyName","/queue/greetings", new Greeting("Bufff!"));
}
```

Adding queue in WebSocketConfig.java:

```java
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic","/queue");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}
```

Change Annotation in GreetingController.java:

```java
@MessageMapping("/hello")
@SendToUser("/queue/greetings")
public Greeting UserGreeting(HelloMessage message, Principal principal) throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
    return new Greeting("Hello, " + HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(message.getName()) + "!");
}
```

And change connect-function in app.js:

```js
var socket = new SockJS('/gs-guide-websocket');
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
    setConnected(true);
    console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
    stompClient.subscribe('user/queue/greetings', function (greeting) {
        showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
    });
});
```

The server uses spring-boot-security and i asured if `MyName` is the right Name by looking up all users with SimpUserRegistry https://stackoverflow.com/a/32215398/11663023). But unfortunately my code  is not working. I already tried this [Sending message to specific user using spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39333910/sending-message-to-specific-user-using-spring) but i do not want Spring to distinguish between sessions but users. I also looked at this [Sending message to specific user on Spring Websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367223/sending-message-to-specific-user-on-spring-websocket) but it did not help because the link doesn't work.

That is my console-log:

```
2020-01-20 17:08:51.352 DEBUG 8736 --- [nboundChannel-3] .WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler : Searching methods to handle SEND /app/hello session=kvv0m1qm, lookupDestination='/hello'
2020-01-20 17:08:51.352 DEBUG 8736 --- [nboundChannel-3] .WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler : Invoking de.iteratec.iteraweb.controllers.GreetingController#UserGreeting[2 args]
2020-01-20 17:08:52.354 DEBUG 8736 --- [nboundChannel-3] org.springframework.web.SimpLogging      : Processing MESSAGE destination=/queue/greetings-userkvv0m1qm session=null payload={"content":"Hello, hey!"}
2020-01-20 17:08:54.882 DEBUG 8736 --- [MessageBroker-2] org.springframework.web.SimpLogging      : Processing MESSAGE destination=/queue/greetings-userkvv0m1qm session=null payload={"content":"Bufff!"}
2020-01-20 17:08:59.883 DEBUG 8736 --- [MessageBroker-4] org.springframework.web.SimpLogging      : Processing MESSAGE destination=/queue/greetings-userkvv0m1qm session=null payload={"content":"Bufff!"}
```

Did I miss a change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you see that the client subscribes successfully to your endpoint?

I think you are missing the first `/` in the client code `'user/queue/greetings'` should be `'/user/queue/greetings'`

Comment: Hey Peter, yes! You are right. This was my mistake.